# Cordova can't find ANDROID_HOME or android in my PATH although they are there

Tags: android, linux, cordova, debian

I set up ANDROID_HOME to my android installation dir as well as adding $ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools and $ANDROID_HOME/tools to my PATH.

When adding the android platform to my project, cordova seems to find android as it needs to run "android update project ....." for doing so but when I'm trying to run "cordova run android" it results in the following error:

```
ERROR: Error: Failed to find 'ANDROID_HOME' environment variable. Try 
setting it manually.
enter code hereFailed to find 'android' command in your 'PATH'. Try 
update your 'PATH' to include path to valid SDK directory.
ERROR running one or more of the platforms: Error: 
[PATH_TO_PROJECT]/platforms/android/cordova/run: Command failed with exit 
code 2
```

It seems like all of a sudden cordova lost access to my environment variables or maybe it's a version conflict of some sort?

I installed android SDK 26 as well as all API and build tools between 19 and 22 (as those are the requirements of the project)
I am running cordova 6.0.0
phonegap 7.0.1
My system is a debian

I tried everything that was suggested in all the other posts with similar issues but still no success and it still gives me the same error.

Probably it's just a little thing I have overlooked but right now I'm clueless and thankful for any idea as to what might be causing the problem.

Comment: what's the output of the command:
echo $ANDROID_HOME
on your terminal?

Comment: it does echo the base directoy I installed android in, just like I set it up

Comment: are you running any of these commands as sudo?

Comment: I am since it didn't work otherwise. cordova was complaining about missing permission when I tried to run it without sudo. 
I did make sure android is executable as sudo though

Comment: Maybe that's why
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/202383/how-to-pass-environment-variable-to-sudo-su

Comment: No I can echo the environment variables even with sudo

Comment: what's the error it gives you when you try to run it without sudo?

Comment: cp: copyFileSync: could not write to dest file (code=EACCES):[PATH_TO_PROJECT]/platforms/android/res/xml/config.xml

ERROR running one or more of the platforms: Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '[PATH_TO_PROJECT]/platforms/android/res/xml/config.xml'
You may not have the required environment or OS to run this project
cordova-custom-config: Skipping auto-restore of config file backup(s) due to config.xml preference

Comment: is [PATH_TO_PROJECT] inside your ~/ (HOME) or in another directory? it should be inside your home so you should have access to it, if it is I would change the permisions to your user with chown -R user:usergroup [PATH_TO_PROJECT]

Comment: It is a git repo inside of my home directory.
Sorry for the stupid question but could you elaborate on changing the permissons to my user?

Comment: What I mean with changing the permissions is that maybe for some reason, these files are under your home but you don't have permissions on then, if you execute the command chown (change owner) with recursive paran (-r) it will change the ownership of the whole directory and you won't have any permission issues.

Comment: sudo chown -R yourusername:yourusername ~/directory

Comment: wow I really didn't think of that one but you nailed it! I knew it had to be something tiny that I didn't think of and this is it! I did exactly as you recommended and it solved my issue.Thanks a lot!

Comment: Good that it helped you, I wrote it as an answer so you can mark it as accepted answer if it was helpful.

Comment: Done. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe for some reason, these files are under your home but you don't have permissions on then, if you execute the command chown (change owner) with recursive param (-r) it will change the ownership of the whole directory and you won't have any permission issues.
sudo chown -R yourusername:yourusername ~/directory

Answer (score 0):

try this one

> export ANDROID_HOME="/home/userName/Android/Sdk/"

in terminal.
this was worked for me.

Comment: Not to be rude but in the first sentence of my post I did set up my environment variables already. Not to mention your response takes a specific android installation directory for granted.

Comment: did you set this in ./~bashrc file too ?